# How to handle return render in django function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
def form_valid(form,request):
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if request.user.is_staff:
            messages.success(request, f'List has been updated!')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'You do not have Admin access!')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        context={
        "form":form,
        }
    return render(request,'movies_list/list_create.html',context)
@login_required
def Award_list_update(request,award_id):
    obj=get_object_or_404(Award_list,award_id=award_id)
    form=Create_Award_list_form(
            data=(request.POST or None),
            files=(request.FILES or None),
            instance=obj,
        )
    form_valid(form,request)
```

> I want to use same template for multiple views so,i decleared a
>   seprate function form_valid for this but i dont know how to handle the
>   return render function.

Comment: what is your goal ?

Comment: You just return the form_valid's result `return form_valid(bla)`

Comment: I am not python expert so,please  elaborate in easyest way .My goal is to use same return render  for multiple views function for this i created a seprate function for this..